# Make mobx data store persistent across app restarts (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I guess this is not an intended usecase for mobx. 
But maybe someone has already implemented something like that?
Using `AsyncStorage` it should be possible to persist and load the stores.

Or is this a sign, that I need somethign other than mobx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/pinqy520/mobx-persist) is the package I was looking for. Works like a charm using AsyncStorage.

Comment: Hey David! can you add a little bit info to your answer as readme of mobx-persist is not so clear for a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

We use [mobx-persist-store](https://github.com/quarrant/mobx-persist-store). It supports any [localStorage like API library](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/), including `AsyncStorage`. The repo has great documentation to easily integrate!

Note: `mobx-persist-store` is compatible with MobX 6 whereas `mobx-persit` hasn't been updated in 5 years and doesn't work with MobX 6